# sql query optimization - NVL REPLACEMENT

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using nvl to check a value. If first statement returns null value then second statement is to be executed. But this is doubling the time of query. any better way to do it?

```
nvl(
    (
            select * from (
                    select tad.ASP_NAME  
                    from TBL_ASP_DETAILS tad 
                    where lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME)||'%'
            )
            where ROWNUM = 1
    )
    ,
    (
            select * from (
                    select tad.ASP_NAME 
                    from TBL_ASP_DETAILS tad 
                    where lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASP_NAME)||'%'
            )
            where ROWNUM = 1
    )
) ASP_NAME
,nvl(
    (
            select * from (
                    select tad.TIERING_2  
                    from TBL_ASP_DETAILS tad 
                    where lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME)||'%'
            )where ROWNUM = 1
    )
    ,
    (
            select * from (
                    select tad.TIERING_2 
                    from TBL_ASP_DETAILS tad 
                    where lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASP_NAME)||'%'
            ) where ROWNUM = 1
    )
) TIERING_2
,nvl(
    (
            select * from (
                    select tad.TIERING_1 
                    from TBL_ASP_DETAILS tad 
                    where lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME)||'%'
            )where ROWNUM = 1
    )
    ,
    (
            select * from (
                    select tad.TIERING_1 
                    from TBL_ASP_DETAILS tad 
                    where lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASP_NAME)||'%'
            )where ROWNUM = 1
    )
)TIERING_1,
```

Comment: Please try to format the SQL a bit better in future, its very difficult to answer when in just 3 lines, but expanded out the problem and solution is clearer

Answer (score 1):

We only have the NVL snippet to go on and not the rest, I can see from the te1.last_name reference that this is a correlated sub-query, since te1 is not within the above code snippet.

A rough idea around it is that you need to join the 2 queries together instead of repeating them - in this instance joined on the basis of te1.last_name since that appears to be what you would want, but without the rest of the query to understand the context, I can't be certain.

Once joined, you can just use nvl (or coalesce for a more ANSI approach)

Performance wise, this is always going to be a bit problematic since you are using full wildcard searching in the where clauses, as well as a lower function.

```
select 
    coalesce(x.asp_name, y.asp_name) as asp_name
    , coalesce(x.tiering_2, y.tiering_2) as tiering_2
    , coalesce(x.tiering_1, y.tiering_1) as tiering_1
from (

                select * from (
                        select 
                                te1.last_name, tad.ASP_NAME, tad.TIERING_2,tad.TIERING_1   
                        from TBL_ASP_DETAILS tad 
                        where lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME)||'%'
                )
                where ROWNUM = 1
) x
full join (
                select * from (
                        select te1.last_name, tad.ASP_NAME, tad.TIERING_2,tad.TIERING_1    
                        from TBL_ASP_DETAILS tad 
                        where lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASP_NAME)||'%'
                )
                where ROWNUM = 1
) y on x.last_name = y.last_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your subqueries using `ORDER BY` and `FETCH`. So I am not sure if it helps the execution time, but as your condition is not indexable this should reduce it:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_ASP_DETAILS tad 
 WHERE lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME)||'%'
    OR lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASP_NAME)||'%'
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN lower(te1.last_name) like '%'||lower(tad.ASSIGNED_FE_LAST_NAME)||'%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
 FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```